# How to overcome error: 'ManyToOneRel' object has no attribute 'verbose_name' in Django application

Tags: django, django-models, attributeerror, many-to-one

In my app I have the following models:

```
class Category(BaseStampModel):
    cat_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name='Cat Id')
    category = models.CharField(max_length=55, verbose_name='Category')

class MasterList(BaseStampModel):
    master_list_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name='Master List Id')
    mast_list_category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, verbose_name='Category')
    # Other fields ...
```

My BaseModel looks like this:

```
class BaseStampModel(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='%(class)s_created', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name='Created by')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, null=True, blank=True)
```

With this I am able to display the model objects and create/update instances.

In my view, when I want to retrieve the `verbose_name` from model "**Category**" using:

```
`model_fields = [(f.verbose_name, f.name) for f in Category._meta.get_fields()]`
```

I am getting the following error in my browser:

> AttributeError: 'ManyToOneRel' object has no attribute 'verbose_name'

If I remove the the FK relationship from the field `mast_list_category` (make it a simple `CharField`) I don't get the error.

Gone through *millions of pages*, but no solution yet.

Any **help** is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the **verbose_name** just like accessing model fields

But there are different ways of getting **verbose_name**. The better way is using `get_field`

```py
model._meta.get_field('field_name').verbose_name
```

In your case, replace the `model` with `Category` and `field_name` with the field you want to get the **verbose_name**

Comment: That's one way of doing it. What I am trying to do is: **create** a `list` of field names and their verbose names for some post processing. And it is working so long as I do not have the FK relationship (pls check my question).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am doing:

Declare an empty array, loop through the model, get the field name and its verbose_name and append.

```
array_model_with_ver_name = []
for f in Category._meta.get_fields():
    if hasattr(f, 'verbose_name'):
        array_model_with_ver_name.append((f.verbose_name, f.name))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, `model._meta._get_fields(reverse=False)` did the job, as the official documentation says

> If reverse=True, then relations pointing to this model are returned.

So as default `model._meta.get_fields()` also returns fields from other models that pointing at our model